# How do properly make a link to another user in PHP

Tags: php, profile

I have a problem that i would like som input on. I have made a list that lists all my users on a little project im working on. on that list i have a link to each existing user so that users can visit each other.

the link look like this.

```
    <td>
        <a href="otheruser.php?id=' .$row['id'].'">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true">Presentation</i>
        </a>
    </td>
```

This links works kinda. Its on the other side the problem starts.
When i get to the users profile page that i want to visit, i use this code to find that users info from the database.

```
<?php
$userId = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = " . intval($userId);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Which also works but I've learned that this is not good form. 
therefore I tried with

```
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = id";
```

Which then shows all users and all theirs presentations and images
  on top of each other, on the same page. So again, how do i show another users 
  presentation properly.
  Also I use PDO not MySQLI if that can be of help.

Comment: Read about [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in the manual. In this particular case, your code is safe, though, since you're casting the value as an integer. But yes, it's better to get use to Prepared Statements and use it consistently.

Comment: you get id in another page check it

Comment: @Bhargav if i dont ask i dont learn. Can you explain that to me like im 11 ? :P

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you, i will read more about prepared statements.

Comment: you pass id with `href` it will get in `php` page   `$userId = $_GET['id'];` simply like that boy

Comment: Another good resource - https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close with

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = id";
```

To use a prepared query with PDO, you can change this in one of two ways, positional or named placeholders.

Positional:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = ?";
```

Named:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = :id";
```

Run the "prepare" , then add the value in the execute statement:

```
$stmt->execute([$userId]); // for positional
$stmt->execute(['id' => $userId]); // for named
```

[(The only proper) PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)  has been a great help getting me up to speed with PDO.